# HTML JS Injection form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have an app that injects an html event listener for submit. We want to do a bit of validation and then call the original submit.  For some reason we keep getting the "interceptor(evt)" called in a recursive call using the following.  Thoughts?

```
 // SUBMIT OVERRIDES

    HTMLFormElement.prototype._submit = HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit;
    HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = interceptor;
    console.log("AddEventListener SUBMIT override");
    window.addEventListener('submit', function submit_el(e) {
        console.log("PK submit calling JS interceptor");
        e.preventDefault();
        interceptor(e);
    }, false);

function interceptor(evt) {
        frm = evt ? evt.target : this;
        if (!frm.onsubmit || (frm.onsubmit() !== false)) { 
            // DO SOME STUFF....
            console.log("Calling the real form submit which should not call the listener");            
            frm._submit(); //form submission
            console.log("Calling the real form submit - COMPLETED");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always cancelling the event, when you call the original onsubmit function you also fire the event listener and do the same thing than first time, try moving `e.preventDefault();` before `return false;` inside interceptor function

you can also make a flag that indicates if the original onsubmit function should run or if the event should be cancelled

Comment: "try moving e.preventDefault(); before the return false"  isn't the fact that e.preventDefault() is called before calling "interceptor(e)"  calling it before the return false?  Lost as to what the suggestion is.

Comment: I tried to say `e.preventDefault()` shoul not be called before `interceptor(e)`, should be called inside

Comment: so why does that work?  The call to interceptor is synchronous.  Why would calling it inside of interceptor just before the return false work?